# Chronic ripgrep / vim Plugin Error on Load: "-complete Used Without -nargs"?

Tags: regex, vim, vim-plugin, ripgrep

I recently added **ripgrep** to my list of **vim plugins** and, immediately after installation, I began receiving this error message whenever I loaded up vim:

```
Error detected while processing /Users/my_macbook/.vim/plugged/vim-ripgrep/plugin/vim-ripgrep.vim:

line  149: E1208: -complete used without -nargs
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Opening the offending file and reviewing lines 148-149 reveals:

```
148 command! -nargs=* -complete=file Rg :call s:Rg(<q-args>)
149 command! -complete=file RgRoot :call s:RgShowRoot()
```

I am well & truly out of my depth here, especially considering that this error was generated by simply installing the plugin; I've made 0 changes to  the underlying file (`vim-ripgrep.vim`).

**Has anyone encountered a similarly chronic error after installing ripgrep and, if so, how did you resolve it?**

Answer (score 6):

Congratulations, you have found a bug in a FOSS program. Next step is to either notify the maintainer via their issue tracker or, if you know how to fix it, submit a patch.

Case in point, the author assigns a completion method, `-complete=file`, but custom commands like `:RgRoot` don't accept arguments by default so the command makes no sense *as-is*: you can't complete arguments if you can't pass arguments.

It only needs a `-nargs=*`, like its upstairs neighbour, `:Rg`, to work properly and the error message is pretty clear about it:

```
line  149: E1208: -complete used without -nargs
```

See `:help -complete`, `:help -nargs`, and more generally, `:help user-commands`.

Answer (score 5):

As the other answer stated, it is a bug in this plugin. There is a currently open pull request to fix this: https://github.com/jremmen/vim-ripgrep/pull/58 **Unfortunately, the repository is currently unmaintained, so it is unlikely to be merged any time soon.** [This active forks page](https://techgaun.github.io/active-forks/index.html#jremmen/vim-ripgrep) may help you identify a new maintainer.

Until there is a new maintainer for vim-ripgrep, I suggest checking out that branch in your `~/.vim/plugged/vim-ripgrep` directory and reopening vim.

Comment: People should not be dissuaded from using the fix by the fact that they won't be getting ripgrep updates since vim-ripgrep's master branch has not been changed in 3 years. Getting this warning every time you are trying to vim a file is really annoying.

Comment: @F1234k true. I was going to edit this to say as much but got sidetracked. I will do that now.

Answer (score 3):

I met the functionally same error on `VIM` plugins while using `vim ~/.vimrc`.

My met error liking yours:

```
Error detected while processing /Users/my_macbook/.vim/plugged/vim-ripgrep

/plugin/vim-ripgrep.vim:
```

I fixed the upstairs with the below:

```
cd /Users/my_macbook/.vim/plugged/vim-ripgrep/plugin/

git pull --rebase
```

END!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using vim-plug, try to change

```
Plug "jremmen/vim-ripgrep"
```

to

```
Plug "miyase256/vim-ripgrep", {'branch': 'fix/remove-complete-from-RgRoot'}
```

---

Here are detail steps:

1. comment `Plug "jremmen/vim-ripgrep"`
2. `:PlugClean`
3. add `Plug "miyase256/vim-ripgrep", {'branch': 'fix/remove-complete-from-RgRoot'}`
4. `:PlugInstall`